# How to get network traffic from a command terminal and display in PHP

Tags: php, linux, networking, terminal, monitoring

i have server ubuntu . I want to show network traffic upload & download in php .

A command is in the terminal for monitoring traffic: [enter link description here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nload-linux-command-to-monitor-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage/) [image]

How can I use command `nload -m`on php.

Like this php :
[image]

**Thanks for helping the source**

Answer (score 0):

nload is interactive-only application , the beat way is `nload > /tmp/network-traffic` and use php to extract the information what you want to display.